# Can't set value to UITextField from calendar in popover

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, uitextfield, uipopovercontroller

Well, in my application there is textfield, which contains some date. Textfield is not editable for user, but it calling for popover with calendar (Tapku Calendar, BTW). I need to paste selected date in calendar into this textfield. I'v trying this code, but it didn't working for me.

Code in Calendar_Popover_Controller.m:

```
// grab (NSString*)Date from calendar and sending it to ChekIn field
- (void)calendarMonthView:(TKCalendarMonthView *)monthView didSelectDate:(NSDate *)d {

NSDate *calendarSelectedDate = [[NSDate alloc] init];
/* Here is formattedDate */

calendarSelectedDate = [calendar dateSelected];
DateForMainView = [formattedDate stringFromDate:calendarSelectedDate];

ViewController *submittedDateToMainView = [[ViewController alloc] init];
submittedDateToMainView.CheckInField.text = [formattedDate stringFromDate:calendarSelectedDate];
}
```

Also I've check other variant. It seems like this:

Calendar_Popover_Controller.m

```
- (void)calendarMonthView:(TKCalendarMonthView *)monthView didSelectDate:(NSDate *)d {

NSDate *calendarSelectedDate = [[NSDate alloc] init];;
/* formattedDate */

calendarSelectedDate = [calendar dateSelected];
DateForMainView = [formattedDate stringFromDate:calendarSelectedDate];
ViewController *submittedDateToMainView = [[ViewController alloc] init];
submittedDateToMainView.DateFromCalendar = DateForMainView;
}
```

Code in ViewController.m:

```
- (BOOL)popoverControllerShouldDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController {
[CheckInField setText:DateFromCalendar];

NSLog(@"For CheckIn TextField DateFromCalendar is: %@", DateFromCalendar);
NSLog(@"popover about to be dismissed");
return YES;
}
```

Here DateFromCalendar == nil anyway. I have no idea to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ViewController` you are using in the `calendarMonthView:didSelectDate:` method is not the one showing on the screen, because you initialize a new one when doing

`ViewController *submittedDateToMainView = [[ViewController alloc] init];`

You need to keep a reference to your existing `ViewController` in your `Calendar_Popover_Controller` and set the `DateFromCalendar` on that one.

Comment: Thanx! I understand, what you talking about, but can you show some sample code? I am new in Xcode.